# How do armor stack with physical defence?

Tags: earthdawn-1e

I've made an Earthdawn campaign and i've used the character pre-generated in Earthdawn Classics intro-game (Kaer Tardim) as a starting point for my players.

To put you in context, the troll has 9 physical defence, hardened leather and a buckler (i think).
I've made them fight an ogre and they looted it's chainmail. All is well.
I've tried looked at the chainmail and hardened leather stats and found that he gains like 2 armor; from +5 to +7.
Is the Armor value of the suit applied to physical defence too?

How does one increases his defences?

Note: i'm using Earthdawn's first edition core and would prefer that edition's answer, if possible .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Armour does not increase Physical Defence it reduces damage taken see *page 194* **"Adjust Damage for Armor"**. Some magical items do increase Physical Defence but not standard ones. For example **"Whip of Defence"** see *page 278*. Otherwise to increase defences you need to spend increases ie from a **Group Pattern**, improved stats or Talent or some circle increases etc.